# Blue Green Residue from leaking Temperature Pressure Relief Value on Rheem Water Heater

Tags: water-heater

I have this blue salt-like residue coming from a leaking temperature and pressure relief valve. Never seen anything like that in crystal form. Thoughts?[image]

Answer (score 3):

Copper corrosion products - you've got a bronze or brass valve (copper alloy) it's hot, and there's water since you say it's leaking.

If it's leaking, replace it.

If it's **operating** (which resembles leaking, but is not leaking) because pressure is too high because you need an expansion tank (or your expansion tank has failed and you need a NEW expansion tank) do that. If it's operating because the temperature is too high, fix that, but it's far less common.

Comment: I agree, replace it. I had a similar problem, the valve showed no corrosion but there was a blue green spot on the concrete floor.  As I remember from 30 years ago the new valve was less than $ 10.